# Theoretical explanation for: Why is KMnO4 stronger oxidizing agent than K2Cr2O7?

Tags: redox, coordination-compounds, transition-metals

I know that it can be explained using the Reduction Potential values. But, can it be explained from their structures or something like that ?

Comment: Redox potentials don't explain anything. By this point main effect of knowing std. potentials, or even knowing they exist, is mostly giving you false impression that there is some objective and universal scale to compare them.

Comment: Maybe it is due to the chromium being at oxidation number +$6$ in $\ce{K2Cr2O7}$ and manganese at a higher oxidation number (+$7$ in $\ce{KMnO4}$)